# Storing a collection of mongoid documents with one operation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, moped

When using `Moped` gem, I can store an array of hashes with:

```
users = [{username: "ben", password: "123456", type: "admin" }, {username: "joe", password: "abcd1234" }]
Mongoid::Sessions.default["collection"].insert(users)
```

With mongoid documents it would look like:

```
class User
  field :username, type: String
  field :password, type: String
end

users.each { |user_hash| User.create(user_hash) }
```

Which means an insertion operation for each.
Do you know a way to keep the single operation method? Maybe something like a transaction in `ActiveRecord`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert Documents back to Hashes and insert them with single call to `#create`:

```
User.create(users.map(&:attributes))
```